# Re-importing existing clearcase views into RationalClearcase client

Tags: clearcase

I have already created my project views from the Rational Clearcase Client. However, something went wrong with my system which left me no choice but to reinstall the Rational Clearcase Client. Now my problem is, I already have the existing folders of the views. How do I re-import it so it will be shown in my Clearcase Navigator?

Thanks!
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view storage is still there, and if you have a view.dat (hidden file) at the root of your view, you can, in a DOS session (I assume Windows here):

```
cd C:\path\to\my\view
clearexplorer .
```

(Note the "space dot" after the `clearexplorer` command)

That will open the ClearCase explorer directly within your view, and will restore the view shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

For Clearcase on eclipse, first check that you have `.copyarea.dat` in your view folder. If it exists, follow these steps:

1. Go to Eclispe > Clearcase menu
2. Clearcase Search
3. On Local Search Select Folder radio
4. Click Add Folder and point to the base view (the folder which contains `.copyarea.dat`)
5. Click Search

Now refresh the Clearcase views. You should be able to see it.

You can use this method to import views.

Comment: If you don't have .copyarea anymore, see this technote : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392432

Answer (score 0):

For Clearcase on eclipse, first check that you have .copyarea.dat in your view folder. If it exists, follow these steps:

1. Go to Eclispe > Clearcase menu > Clearcase Search
2. On ClearCase Search select: On Local Search Select Folder radio
3. Click Add Folder and point to the directory that contains .copyarea.dat
4. Click Search
5. On the treeview "My Views"  click mouse's right button and select the option refresh the Clearcase views. You should be able to see it.

You can use this method to import views.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my $0.02...

If we're talking about snapshot views, There are some that require you to update the view from the CLI before you can see them in the GUI.

If you're referring to dynamic views, @VonC's  method will work. You may also be able to get them back by refreshing view shortcuts.